# Какие триггеры/процедуры/функции стоит использовать в Интернет-магазине?

Tags: mysql, интернет-магазин

Есть база данных для Интернет-магазина, состоящая из 6 таблиц, которая предназначена для самых элементарных вещей: хранения инфы о пользователях, товарах, заказах и поставках.
Какие триггеры/процедуры/функции стоит использовать в Интернет-магазине? Не обязательно сложные.
База данных представлена ниже.

[image]

Для работы с базой пишу программу на C# Windows Forms с помощью коннектора, но задача состоит в создании триггеров и функций на уровне самой базы данных.

Comment: Какие вам нужны, те и используйте. Если ни в каких не появилось необходимости - никакие и не используйте

Comment: @andreymal Мне нужно создать хотя бы 1 триггер, процедуру и функцию. Я курсовую пишу. А что писать - не знаю! Нам толком и не рассказали, для чего именно они нужны. Поэтому и спрашиваю, какие есть идеи, что будут не лишними.

Comment: Триггеры при построении МАГАЗИНА можно использовать разве что для предрасчётного накопления статистики ( плевать на плюс-минус, но близко к истине, зато не грузит сервер), скажем, расчёт популярных товаров по категориям... Процедура может периодически эту статистику пересчитывать точно. Функция.. ну скажем выполнять перевод цен из одной валюты в другую...

Comment: @Akina Ооо, вот это то, что надо! Спасибо! Где тут ставить лайк?